# Map JSON to an object member in spring controller

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a basic java object:

```
public class Condition {

    int id;
    int fieldImplId;
    String property;
    String message;
    boolean applyIfEvaluatesTo;
    boolean newValue;
    List<Expression> expressions;  
}
```

Now my Expression object contains a n-List of nested expressions.  Saving all that to a DB is a pain in the butt.  SO is there a way (annotation?)  where I could have a class like  where the expressions memeber is a JSON (String) that I can save to the DB as a string.  (All the logic is done in javascript so I have no need to javatize it.)

The body would look like this:

```
 "conditions": 
  {
    "id": 4,
    "fieldId": 0,
    "property": "isVisible",
    "message": null,
    "applyIfEvaluatesTo": false,
    "newValue": true,
    "expression": {
      "operator": "OR",
      "args": [
        {
          "operator": "AND",
          "args": [
            {
              "fieldId": "zip",
              "operator": "IS_VALID",
              "operands": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The point being that I do no care at all what value "expression" has (it could have an n number of args. I just want to save it to the DB.  And I really need to be able to be mapped cleanly like thus:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void createCondition(@RequestBody Condition condition) {
```

Is there any way to just say,  "this element is a string"

SO at the end of the day the object would just look like this:

```
public class Condition {
    int id;
    int fieldImplId;
    String property;
    String message;
    boolean applyIfEvaluatesTo;
    boolean newValue;
    String expressions;  
}
```

Comment: please give more explanation about what are you looking for, did just want to replace the expression with a String (the same as `property`) then parse it later ?

Comment: Do you want to put only `List<Expression>` to DB or `Condition` object?

Comment: @yaitloutou  Yes,  I can build the coditions object just fine...  I just want to cheat here.  The front end people are crazy and I just want to not have to deal with whatever convoluted scheme they come up with.

Comment: I see, I think [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) may be useful for you, so, instead List<Expression> you can use List<String> where the string is a json object, that you can easily parse with the jackson API.

Comment: another (fix), would be something along the line `generateRandomInt(){return 42;}` until the front-end guys settle for an expression  :)